How to sort a vector in Rust that only has partial ordering?
I have a vector of elements that has partial ordering. It's not just floats where NaN cannot be compared to anything else but otherwise it has total ordering. It is more along the lines of A < B if A is a proper subset of B. I want the result to hold the invariant that if A < B, then the index of A should be less than the index of B. If neither A < B nor B < A, then the relative position of A and B doesn't matter.
Is there a way to achieve this without implementing my own sorting algorithm?

Isn't that what sort_by and sort_unstable_by is for?

@t.niese sort_by still claims to require a total order to avoid undefined ordering. It requires you to be able to return a relative ordering for any pair of elements in your collection at runtime.

Note that if you truly have sets and your items have a total order, then you can define a total order which will respect the properties you specified.

@cafce25 No I don't, and it wouldn't work anyway. Any arbitrary ordering would not work, only something that preserves the already existing partial ordering relations. What I need is a sorting algorithm that works with partial ordering.

It's not possible in general, so if you can add more info about the types you're trying to sort that would be helpful.

You can combine your existing ordering with an arbitrary total ordering so that your ordering takes precedence. Use your own function similar to then, but for Option<Ordering>.

I'm working on geometries. Areas. I want a sorting so that if one area is contained within another, it should appear earlier in the list. It's as general as you can get.

Looks like you need some kind of topological sort. If you don't want to write the algorithm yourself, you can try some existing crates like https://crates.io/crates/topological-sort .

As mentioned in the comments, a topological sorting algorithm can be used to give an ordering to elements in a partially ordered set. The typical algorithms have complexity O(V+E) where V is the number of elements and E is the number of element pairs with an ordering. There are existing Rust crates that can do that: topological-sort, topologic, and topo-sort come up from a quick search but I can't personally vouch for a particular one though the first is most popular.
However, a problem with using a topological sort when you just have a Vec<T> and T: PartialOrd is that you need to first build a dependency graph in order to use those algorithms. And doing so would require iterating over all element pairs to see if they have an ordering, which makes the overall sort O(N^2) just with prepwork. If you already have a graph-like structure, or you can more smartly determine the orderings, then this is likely the way to go. However, if not, there's a more direct way.

Here is such an algorithm that does the sort in-place that is O(N^2):
pub fn partialordsort<T: PartialOrd>(mut items: &mut [T]) {
    let mut presorted = 1;
    
    while items.len() > presorted {
        'make_start_min: loop {
            for i in presorted..items.len() {
                let ordering = T::partial_cmp(&items[0], &items[i]);
                if let Some(Ordering::Greater) = ordering {
                    items.swap(presorted, i);
                    items[0..presorted+1].rotate_right(1);
                    presorted += 1;
                    continue 'make_start_min;
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        presorted = usize::max(presorted - 1, 1);
        items = &mut items[1..];
    }
}

See it working on the playground with a "range" type ordered by total-overlap.
Essentially you must use a "naïve" sorting algorithm, think bubble-sort, since the comparisons you need to perform are still combinatorial (i.e. N^2) and can't rely on the guarantees from Ord to infer orderings from other elements.
The above is a modified version of insertion-sort that does some additional tracking to reduce some comparisons (i.e. if we know B < C and now see A < B, that means there's an ordering A < C and don't need to check that). The algorithm has some nice properties:

It will sort A < B < C in order even when partial_cmp(A, C) is None; this isn't important in your scenario but might be in other PartialOrd use-cases.
It will return a result even if the comparisons form a cycle (i.e. A < B < C < A); the result obviously won't be sorted since there is no possible sorted order, but at least it won't infinitely loop.
Its runtime complexity is similar between random, presorted, and reversed inputs and similar whether the elements are mostly comparable or mostly incomparable though it will do more comparisons with less moves and vice-versa depending on the scenario.

I didn't find much info on partial-order sorting without building a graph with edges so if there is a better in-place technique (or if the above is flawed) please let me know.

That all being said, that is all actually unnecessary in your particular use-case. Ordering by A < B if A is a proper subset of B and the geometric equivalent you mentioned in the comments (rectangles fully overlapped) is actually trivially total-order-able by sorting on size. Since A being a subset of B means that A is strictly smaller than B, ordering by size(A) < size(B) will automatically grant you the proper subset ordering as well. So you can just do, roughly:
.sort_by_key(|element| size(element)) 

See it working on the playground with the same "range" type above.
